# How do I access forms in a form_list in the done method in formwizard?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views, formset, formwizard

from views.py

```
def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):
        user = self.request.user
        resumes = form_list[0]
        resumes.user = user
        resumes.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('resumes:my-resumes'))
```

from forms.py

```
class ResumeForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Resume
        fields = ['name', ]
```

from models.py

```
class Resume(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Hi, I'm trying to configure the done method in my Wizard view (extends SessionWizardView). I want to access the first form in the form_list but this throws an error? What am I doing wrong?

I'm trying to insert user into a modelform before saving it (resume requires a user foreign key). I will also need to insert resume foreign key in other steps of the wizard form.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is method for that:
[get_form_step_data](https://django-formtools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/wizard.html#formtools.wizard.views.WizardView.get_form_step_data)

and you must pass name of the step form.

Comment: Missed that! Thanks!

Comment: Should I call this in the done view, manipulate the data and save instance of model? Am I going in the right direction?